# generation of numbers that are x percent likely to be a duplicate

Tags: python-2.7

i am generating random numbers currently like this :

```
rand.sample(range(1, network_ip_node_size))
```

this generates a random number from 1 to x and is working fine

however what i am trying to do is say i have a list `(list_of_nodes)` for example, i want to generate a random number, but say have a probability of   20% of being a number already contained within the `list_of_nodes`

what is the most effecient way of achieving this ?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want there to be a higher probability of the randomly generated number to be one that's already in that list? 20% higher?

Comment: A 20% chance the random number generated is already contained within the list

Comment: Well, the only way to ensure that is by having your list contain 20% of all possible numbers. Aside from that, I guess you could have a variable keep track of the number of times a number from the list was generated in percentage & if it gets too high or too low, throw out the last result & generate another random number.